# Are Laravel 4.x docs on extending authentication in error?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

Laravel 4.x documentation states that the Auth::extend() callback should "[Return implementation of Illuminate\Auth\UserProviderInterface](http://laravel.com/docs/extending#authentication)":

```
Auth::extend('riak', function($app)
{
    // Return implementation of Illuminate\Auth\UserProviderInterface
});
```

However, numerous [web tutorials](http://www.karlvalentin.de/1903/write-your-own-auth-driver-for-laravel-4.html) on extending Laravel 4 authentication state that Auth::extend() should return an instance of Illuminate\Auth\Guard, which takes an instance of UserProviderInterface as an argument:

```
Auth::extend('example', function($app) {
    $provider =  new \Example\Auth\ExampleUserProvider();

    return new \Illuminate\Auth\Guard($provider, $app['session']);
});
```

I am using this latter approach in a Laravel 4.0 app and it is working. I could not get the  [official documented Laravel 4.x approach](http://laravel.com/docs/extending#authentication) to work. I checked the Laravel upgrade guides and there is no mention of any API change in this area.

Are the Laravel 4.x docs in error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has since been cleared up in the Laravel docs: "the callback passed to the Auth::extend method should return an implementation of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard."

For more information, see: [Laravel 5.2 Authentication - Adding Custom Guards](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#adding-custom-guards)